# When I pass data to a view I get an "undefined variable" error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, view, undefined

Please help me: I get an error when I pass data to a view. I think it's the correct procedure but i get error..

- **Controller:**

  ```
  $data['success']='1';
  $this->load->view('user_control/register', $data);
  ```
- **View:**

  ```
  echo $success;
  ```
- **Got Error:**

  ```
  A PHP Error was encountered
  Severity: Notice
  Message: Undefined variable: success
  Filename: views/register.php
  Line Number: 79
  ```

Comment: We need more than that. Post at least the complete controller function.

Comment: seems like your view is not loading correctly. You are pointing to the user_control directory, but the error is not recognizing that. Provide more information. Also, how are your routes setup? would there be something there that's conflicting with the names?

Comment: is the view you are trying to load sitting here: `application\views\user_control\register.php` ?

Comment: are you going to follow up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is working perfectly. Take a look at my screen shots and try emulate.

**My Controller**

[image]

**My View (Code)**

[image]

And finally the result on the screen.

[image]

If it is still not working, make sure you have you are running Codeigniter in htdocs on a Lampp or Xampp stack.

Answer (score 0):

Not a codeigniter programmer but you should check your view Filename from your controller you have passed `$this->load->view('user_control/register', $data);` i guess filename should be in

> views/user_control/register.php